# Ошибка .htaccess перенаправления

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Apache 2.4-x64 локальный сервер
`.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
```

В большинстве случаев все проходит правильно — перенаправление на `index.php`, например `sitename.loc/Анапа.html`, `sitename.loc/Брянск.html`, но, например, `sitename.loc/Астрахань.html` или `sitename.loc/Архангельск.html` выдает **Object not found 404**.
Регулярное выражение в `.htaccess` самое общее, должно перенаправлять любой запрос, не удается уловить зависимость от адреса в url и 404 ошибкой. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: У вас очень мудреные правила mod_rewrite. Мне кажется можно было сделать и проще. Но действительно, разницы между «открытием» Анапа.html и «не открытием» Астрахань.html тут не просматривается. Возможно все вопросы к движку.

Comment: Да собственно даже файл с одним единственным правилом RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA] никак не меняет картину происходящего